# jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail getting this error while creating Example GXT project

Tags: gwt, gxt

`[ERROR] jreLeakPrevention.gcDaemonFail java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.GC at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.jreLeakPrevention(JettyLauncher.java:899) at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:722) at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:636) at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:898) at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:705) at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432) 2023-02-17 20:50:58.161:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT Starting Jetty on port 8888`

getting the above mentioned error while creating Example GXT project, i am using Java 11,GWT 2.9.0,GXT 4.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a harmless warning, indicating only that the leak prevention APIs used in older JDKs are not present. If they are missing, GWT emits this message, then continues without them.

This has been [removed in the main branch](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/commit/41a34557a6bf6e54d3b9867b346f7a91b5c8d095), and will be part of the next release, GWT 2.11.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How to solve this issue exactly? I have followed the steps mentioned in sencha documentation for installation and creation of project but still facing issue. I couldn't even create a sample project. Not sure what i am missing here.. Could you provide basic steps? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue you're having? This is just log noise, and has no impact on whether anything else works in DevMode - are you seeing later log messages?